# SQLselect count with case/when

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have the following table:

```
Id  Type 
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   A
```

I would like to create new table that counts the number of rows which each type has. It is easy to create each table for each type counting, but I would like to make it better in looks and also the performance, so is it possible to do this in one query? I have come up with a query like below but it does not work. The error said that "Result of WHEN clause 2 is not the same data type as the preceding result". 
Help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.Statistics_Count AS
   SELECT 
      COUNT(Id) as total,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = "A" then Id else . end) as typeA,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = "B" then Id else . end) as typeB,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = "C" then Id else . end) as typeC,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Type <> "A" then Id else . end) as nonTypeA
   FROM WORK.ListTable;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS solution is not to use PROC SQL for such a thing.  SQL is always going to be a bit slower or harder/messier to code with exceptions (without the NotTypeA this would be easier).  In SAS, PROC TABULATE and PROC FORMAT will give you that easily with a quick transpose afterwards.  A bit more code but a lot more flexible.

```
data have;
input Id Type  $;
datalines;
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  A
;;;;
run;

proc format lib=work;
value $typeF (multilabel notsorted)
'A'='TypeA'
'B'='TypeB'
'C'='TypeC'
'B','C'='NonTypeA'
;;;;
run;

proc tabulate data=have out=want;
format type $typef.;
class type/mlf preloadfmt order=data;
tables type*n;
run;

proc transpose data=want out=want_t(drop=_NAME_);
var N;
id type;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks alot, Joe. This is exactly what I want. Worked perfectly. I will look up more on sas proc.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
Select Type , count(Type) as cnt
from WORK.Statistics_Count
group by Type
```

code updated as per comment.

```
    Select Type, count(Type) as cnt from  ( 
Select Type from WORK.Statistics_Count
where Type in ('A','B','C')

Union All

Select 'Others' as Type from WORK.Statistics_Count
where Type not in ('A','B','C'))z
group by Type
```

Comment: If there are more types than those I would like to count, is there any other way to group the rest as "others" instead of doing it manually? For example, I only need to count for 3 types A,B,C, but there are 26 types from a-z, so from c-z would be counted as others?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think union all would be bad with table with around 1 million records?

Comment: @Luke Henz I am not very sure on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select type,count(*) NoofRows from tbl group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the counts in a `SELECT` by doing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM WORK.ListTable
GROUP BY Type
```

See MySQL [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) (Aggregate) functions.

Comment: Why are you suggesting MySQL solution for this?  This isn't MySql.

Answer (score 0):

```
`proc sql noprint;`
 create table test as
 select * , 
   case 
    when type = "A" then count(id) 
   end as typeA
   ,
 case 
    when type = "B" then count(id) 
   end as typeB
   ,
 case 
    when type = "C" then count(id) 
   end as typeC
   ,
 case 
    when type ne "A" then count(id) 
   end as nontypeA

 from datain;
quit;


*  if you have many types, you can try this method below:  ;

data a;
 set datain;
   output;
  if type ne "A" then type="not A";
   output;
run;
  proc sql noprint;
  create talbe test1
   select * , count(id) as count
  from datain
  group by type
  order by id;
  quit;
proc transpose data=test1 out= final;
 id type;
 by id;
 var count;
run;
```